# Multiplying column values by column header in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to multiply all the column values by the column header in pandas dataframe which is shown in pivot table. Does anyone have a good solution for this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['one2', 'one3', 'one3', 'one4' ],
                   'Requested Volume in Million':[5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 2.2],
                   'BOX':[1,2,3,4],
                   'Date':['2018-06-14', '2016-12-06', '2017-01-05', '2016-11-22']}) 

df2=pd.pivot_table(df, columns ='Requested Volume in Million',index =['ID','Date'], values ='BOX', aggfunc ='count', margins=True,  fill_value=0)
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x : x * float((x.name)[0]) if type(x.name[0]) != float else x, axis=0)
```

Comment: If sample input in text format is provided, we could try to provide a solution.

Comment: Thanks, Manjunath. I've added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with apply and a lambda. Each column name, which we cast to a float, can be accessed with .name. We use axis 1 to operate on the columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'0.5':[0.5, 0.2, -0.2, 0.5 ],
                   '2':[10, 5, -5, 10]})   

df = df.apply(lambda x : x * float(x.name), axis=0)
```

Output df:

```
    0.5     2
0   0.25    20.0
1   0.10    10.0
2   -0.10   -10.0
3   0.25    20.0
```

Edit Pivot Table Solution:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({5: {0: 20130320, 1: 20130320, 2: 20130320, 3: 20130320, 4: 20130320},
 10: {0: 8, 1: 12, 2: 16, 3: 20, 4: 24},
 20: {0: 1, 1: 3, 2: 5, 3: 7, 4: 9},
 30: {0: 20, 1: 30, 2: 10, 3: 40, 4: 30},
 40: {0: 400, 1: 500, 2: 500, 3: 200, 4: 300},
 50: {0: 1000, 1: 1100, 2: 900, 3: 1300, 4: 800}})


df = pd.pivot_table(df, values=[30, 40, 50], index=[5], columns=[10],  aggfunc='mean', margins=True)

df = df.apply(lambda x : x * float((x.name)[1]) if type(x.name[1]) != str else x, axis=0)
```

Output df:

```
    30                      40                      50
      10    8   12  16  20  24  All     8   12  16  20  24  All     8   12  16  20  24  All
5                                                                       
20130320   20   30  10  40  30  26.0    400 500 500 200 300 380.0   1000    1100    900 1300    800 1020.0
All        20   30  10  40  30  26.0    400 500 500 200 300 380.0   1000    1100    900 1300    800 1020.0
```

Edit with OP's data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PID':['CIRC', 'CIRC0006', 'CIRC0054', 'CIRC9876' ],
                   'Requested Volume in Million':[5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 2.2],
                   'LiN2 Position in Box':[1,2,3,4],
                   'Freezing Date':['2018-06-14', '2016-12-06', '2017-01-05', '2016-11-22']}) 

df2=pd.pivot_table(df, columns ='Requested Volume in Million',index =['PID','Freezing Date'], values ='LiN2 Position in Box', aggfunc ='count', margins=True,  fill_value=0)

df3 = df2.apply(lambda x : x * float((x.name)) if type(x.name) != str else x, axis=0)
```

Ouput df2:

```
    Requested Volume in Million 2.2 5.0 6.0 7.0 All
PID Freezing Date                   
CIRC    2018-06-14  0   1   0   0   1
CIRC0006    2016-12-06  0   0   1   0   1
CIRC0054    2017-01-05  0   0   0   1   1
CIRC9876    2016-11-22  1   0   0   0   1
All     1   1   1   1   4
```

Output df3:

```
    Requested Volume in Million 2.2 5.0 6.0 7.0 All
PID Freezing Date                   
CIRC    2018-06-14  0.0 5.0 0.0 0.0 1
CIRC0006    2016-12-06  0.0 0.0 6.0 0.0 1
CIRC0054    2017-01-05  0.0 0.0 0.0 7.0 1
CIRC9876    2016-11-22  2.2 0.0 0.0 0.0 1
All     2.2 5.0 6.0 7.0 4
```

Comment: Very interesting. That's easier than I thought. At the bottom and right of the dataframe or pivot table, I have "All" Column, (coming form the margins =True in pivot table) which sums up all the column values, giving me "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'All'.

Comment: Can you make margins=False when you make the table? I was just working through an pivot table example and that made it work. Will post momentarily.

Comment: No, I need the Magins=True parameter there. I am trying to automate this pivot table which should include total

Comment: See my edit. You may need to change the `(x.name)[1])` to `(x.name)[0]` for your data structure. In the future, it's helpful if you can post a way to recreate your df rather than a screenshot.

Comment: We just need to have the total at the very end, not by subtotal. Running the code gives me "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable". Thanks Matthew.

Comment: It would be very helpful to post a reproductible example. You can do this by taking a slice of your df and using .to_dict() which you can paste here. It's also important to post your desired output. Screenshots are not very useful.

Comment: I think it maybe due to a data type error but i will produce the example

Comment: I just edited my post and added the sample code

Comment: Thanks for posting data. It's working now. Needed to remove the indexers from .name.

Comment: Apparently, the multiplication of the column values and column header is not working. Does it work on yours?

Comment: Yes, it's working for me. I just posted output.

Comment: yeah I think it's working properly on our sample but mine is not working atm

Comment: I might have to look into it but that was a great help. Thanks Matthew!

Comment: Found where the issue is coming from. Had to change the df1['Freezing Date'] = df1['Freezing Date'].astype(str) and now it works!

Comment: Great! I'd appreciate it if you could mark this as the accepted answer. Thanks! :)